# Is there a way to skip or continue in Switch expression or does every branch need to return something?

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to add to a list only when the switch expression finds something like so:

```
List<drivedType> derivedObjects = new()

derivedObjects.Add(baseObject switch
{
    derivedType d when d.field != 1 => d,
    _ => // Here I would put somthing like "continue" but it's not accepted
});
```

Anything of the like possible?

Comment: All expressions have to return a value. What would `Add` do in the default case?

Comment: Wouldnt this be much easier/clearer with LINQ or am I missing something?

Comment: Where does `baseObject` come from? If it comes from a list or IEnumerable, a `Where().Select().ToList()` could replace this code. If there's only one instance, it would be better to use an `if clause` and only use `Add` if the condition succeeded

Comment: @maccettura Not sure how to use LINQ, can you post the answer, and I can accept it. Still learning, sorry.

Comment: @Nomnom what are you trying to do? Where does `baseObject` come from? And why use a switch expression? What is `r` ?

Comment: This is a lot like trying to fit a square peg into a round hole. The beauty of switch expressions is that they _do_ give you a return for every case.  If that isn't what you're trying to accomplish, you've picked the wrong peg.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you cast a base object to a derived one using `Where().Select().ToList()`? I need to type match at runtime.

Comment: `OfType<SomeType>()` will filter by type. Again, what are you trying to do? The current code makes little sense

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos r was a typo sorry, it's d, d is an object of type derivedType

Comment: @Nomnom if you can edit your question to show what type `baseObject` is, I think you would attract a lot more answers

Comment: @Nomnom the question makes little sense. The appropriate code depends on what you actually want to do. Filter a list of objects by type? Add a single object. based on some condition? Something else?

Comment: Have you considered eg `if(baseObject is DerivedType d && d.Field != 1) list.Add(d);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'd like to filter a list of objects made up of a base type with a specific derived type AND make sure one of the fields do not match, and create a list out of that.

Comment: @CaiusJard that actually makes a lot of sense -_-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear what this code is trying to do. It may be a snippet from code that tries to filter a list of objects by type. It may be an attempt to insert a single object based on type. Or something completely different.

If the intention is to filter a list of objects by type, LINQ can be used to filter *and* create the final list:

```
var derivedObjects= baseObjects.OfType<DerivedObject>()
                               .Where(d=>d.Field !=1)
                               .ToList();
```

If the intention is to insert a single object :

```
if(baseObject is DerivedType d && d.Field !=1)
{
    derivedObjects.Add(d);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Here I would put somthing like `continue`

No `continue`, the switch expression is an *expression*, it has to return something.

The only exception in C# is that these expressions (`switch` expressions, conditional expressions, etc) are allowed to throw instead, much like a function is allowed to throw instead of return a value. So you could do something like this, and indeed it's a very common pattern:

```
derivedObjects.Add(baseObject switch
{
    derivedType d when d.field != 1 => r,
    _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
});
```

Edit: Just in case you don't know, there is actually an easier way to write your code, without that `when`:

```
derivedObjects.Add(baseObject switch
{
    derivedType { field: not 1 } d => r,
    _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
});
```

Comment: It would be better to use `if` and *not* add anything if the condition failed

Comment: Depends on your use case, there are definitely cases where you have to support each individual item with customized code (like the example here), and anything you don't support is an error, not something to silently ignore.

Comment: In this question, it seems all possible C# 9 features were used whether they fit or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is better done with a switch statement instead of a switch expression

```cs
List<drivedType> derivedObjects = new()

switch(baseObject)
{
    case derivedType d when d.field != 1:
        derivedObjects.Add(d);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

I.e., when the value is as desired, add it, otherwise do not. But since you have only one valid case, an if statement seems more appropriate than a switch statement. You must use the `is` keyword to introduce a pattern when not inside a case label: `baseObject is pattern_expression`

In C# 9.0 you can also use the new [relational and disjunctive patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements)

```
case derivedType { field: < 1 or > 1 } d:
```